# my python is not showing in command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

When I enter the term "python" or "py" in my windows command prompt I receive a message that Err: Python is not recognized as an internal or external command. Although I have already installed a fresh python version 3.9 recently, and it was working on command prompt till yesterday. I went into the Environment variables section and meanwhile copied the python 3.9 file location from windows start, and replaced the path variable with my copied path of python. And then I tried again to find python but to my surprise, the command prompt still showed Err: Python is not recognized as an internal or external command. Please help me with this issue, as it is slowing my work down.

Comment: Did you restart command prompt? Is the folder your python executable is installed in the output of `echo %PATH%`? What is the folder you copied into your `%PATH%` variable?

Comment: This may sound very stupid, but have you tried rebooting your computer? As @Axe319 mentions, It often happens that changes only take effect after restarting the command prompt or rebooting your system

Comment: Yes I rebooted my pc and it gave the same response